# Change serrialization of collection in Odata

Tags: c#, json.net, odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following objects:

```
public class Car 
{
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual IList<Spec> Specs { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Spec
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set;}
   public virtual string Info { get; set;}
}

 public class Owner: ILast
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set;}
   public virtual string FullName{ get; set;}
   public virtual DateTime DateTime { get; set;}
}
```

The `Car` have 1:M with `Owner`, but I want when I request `Car` entities I get not array but single entity.

```
public class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T : IEntity
{
        private readonly IRepository<T, TKey> _repo;

        public BaseReadController(IRepository<T, TKey> repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get()
        {
          return _repo.Query();
        }
}
```

The `Query` returns `IQuerable` and have predicate which select entity with last `DateTime` property, if it implement `ILast` interface. For example we have the following data in the `Owner` table:

Owner table:

```
id | FullName | DateTime | CarId
1      name1    12.01.13   1
2      name2    15.04.15   1
```

the query will return only second one.

in the JSON result I will get(assume that `Spec` table have 2 records too):

```
Car = {
  id: 1,
  Specs: {
     [0]: object with spec properties,
     [1]: object with spec properties,   
  },
  Owners: {
     [0]: {
         id: 1,
         FullName: 'name2',
         DateTime: '15.04.5'
      }
  }
}
```

But, I want to change serialization, `Owners` property always contains one record. I want to get the following JSON:

```
Car = {
      id: 1,
      Specs: {
         [0]: object with spec properties,
         [1]: object with spec properties,   
      },
      Owners: {
         id: 1,
         FullName: 'name2',
         DateTime: '15.04,.5'
      }
    }
```

We can determine entity by interface.

PS. I'm using `OData`.

Comment: It's just interface with one property `DateTime`

Comment: If Car has only one owner, then why do you have owners as its property. Keep it just Owner (and not list)

Comment: @Guanxi: because there are many records may be. But user have to see only one. It's like historical entity.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this by writing custom serialization, but I won't recommend overwriting an array item representation with single object, as then that would not be a standard.

I would suggest create two properties in your Car object, one Owner and another past owners, and don't expose past owners to the user by using JSON ignore.

Comment: I'm using `OData` for data access.